# heml chart yaml file "http" instead "curl"

Tags: yaml, kubernetes-helm

I am new to helm chart when so i want curl command to be used as http in yaml file.

Example code :

`imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.entityManager.image.pullPolicy }}`
`name: {{ include "entity-manager.fullname" . }}`
`ports:`
`- containerPort: 1025`
`protocol: TCP`
`lifecycle:`
`preStop:`
`exec:`
`command:`
`- /bin/sh`
`- -c`
`- curl -X PUT {{ .Values.entityManager.eurekaAddress }}`
`{{- if .Values.entityManager.readinessProbe.enabled }}`
`readinessProbe:`
`exec:`
`command:`
`- sh`
`- -c`
`- curl --silent http://localhost:1025/actuator/health | grep --quiet -e`
`'^{\"status\"\:\"UP\".*}$'`
`

how it can be done for `- curl --silent http://localhost:1025/actuator/health | grep --quiet -e`

Comment: Sorry it is not very clear what is it you are asking exactly.

Comment: @jabbson , I want http instead of curl in yaml file

Answer (score 0):

This is more like a k8s liveness detection problem, you may be able to refer to this k8s document to solve [k8s liveness](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-a-liveness-http-request)

The k8s container supports three methods for liveness detection:

- `Exec` specifies the action to take
- `HTTPGet` specifies the http request to perform
- `TCPSocket` specifies an action involving a TCP port

But if http is used here, only the `GET` method can be supported.

Like this.

```yaml
imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.entityManager.image.pullPolicy }}
name: {{ include "entity-manager.fullname" . }}
ports:
  - containerPort: 1025
    protocol: TCP
lifecycle:
preStop:
exec:
command:
  - /bin/sh
  - -c
  - curl -X PUT {{ .Values.entityManager.eurekaAddress }}
{{- if .Values.entityManager.readinessProbe.enabled }}
readinessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: http://xxx.xx.xx
    port: xxxx
```